# Products are blank in admin order screen, invoice screen ends up blank, cannot complete orders

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Running Magento 1.9.0.1, brand new install with just a few plugins on it. When a product is purchased on our website, the admin order screen under "Items Ordered" is completely blank. The order is also stuck in "processed", we cannot complete it. Clicking "invoice" just shows a blank invoice screen.

Here are screenshots:
[image: order screen]

[image: invoice screen]

Answer (score 1):

I have run across similar issues that required me to manually remove the entire cache folder via either ssh or ftp

Comment: Thanks, caching was disabled the whole time but I'll see what happens with the next order after doing this